# How to replace icon with image in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replace `fa fa-calculator` with an image link, how can I do that. I am new to all this and just trying to get my head around.

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
                
                <i class="fa fa-calculator fa-5x"></i>
                <h4>Images, Logo & Content</h4>
                <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
                  
                </div>

Comment: Please edit your post and add as much as code and info to your question and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article before posting a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are fonts bro, so just replace all the tag with an

```
<img src="yourimage">
```

And remember to change with an image with a little size, like an icon.

In the internet are a lot of set of icons so i dont recommend to change the icons with images.

If it's an image link its just

```
<a href="yourlink"><img src="yourimage"></a>
```

Comment: Hermes, many thanks for your prompt help, as I mentioned above I am new to this so appreciate your patience, advice and all the help.Just a quick one, replacing icon with image wouldn't affect the responsive part of the site? correct>> is there any particular reason you recommend  using icons, not images??

Comment: You are welcome. If this solution worked for you please feel free to accept my answer as correct

Comment: Sorry i dont read the edit lf your comment. If you use the class responsive for the images dont affect. The size too. I recommend the icon font because its a pack of all if no you need a folder called img or anything with all your icons, the size of the font icons its 20kb for example and thats the size of 2 icon images, thats a lot of advantage

Comment: Many Thanks bro, that really explain all. much appreciated.

Comment: Hermes-- going back to your first reply you did mention that there are so many icons online, now I would like to know how to use those icons within the code, for example, this icon http://www.iconarchive.com/show/developer-icons-by-graphics-vibe/seo-icon.html

Comment: which file I need to download and where to place it in code?

Comment: The file that u need bro, if your site its using small fonts use the smaller but if you are using for an example a design like metro from Windows use the 64x64. For a real pack of icons resizable i recommend to you this https://material.io/icons/

Comment: Thanks a lot, all is much appreciated